# What is the difference between form action="" and form action="."?

Tags: html, forms, action

Is there any difference beween:

```
<form action="">
```

... and:

```
<form action=".">
```

?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

empty string normally indicates current url (e.g., `http://example.com/a/test.html`)
`'.'` - current 'directory' (e.g., `http://example.com/a/`)

Comment: Doesn't '.' indicate the current directory and '../' indicate the parent directory?

Comment: Depends on your definition of 'parent'. The 'current' directory is the 'parent' of the current file...